# how to authenticate users in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have added some URLs in my Django API for posting deleting and putting data and I don't know how to authenticate users first and give some of them to use these methods and ban some of them

Comment: Can you please specify what kind of authentication you want, do you want login user to post, put and delete your data.

Comment: @shankarj67 I want super user to do these actions and other people can't

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use inbuilt decorator

> @user_passes_test

then you can specify who can access your views just like below,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def admin_user(user):
    return user.is_superuser # write your logic here

@user_passes_test(admin_user)
def your_view(request):
    --------
```

Have a look at the documentation for more clarification: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test

Comment: you can use this @login_required, but the problem is that all the users can access my views.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the tag django-rest-framework, I assume that your view is being created with Django REST Framework.

First, you should force users to be **[authenticated to use the API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)**. Second, you need to define what **[types of permissions are needed](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)** to perform the actions.

You stated that Django Super Users should be able to perform these actions. Thus, you could create a custom permission to make sure that only a user that is a Django Super User will have permission:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsSuperUser(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to admin users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_superuser = request.user and request.user.is_superuser
        if not is_superuser and request.user:
            # Your ban logic goes here
            pass
        return is_superuser
```

Then on your view, you can do:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from your_app.permissions import IsSuperUser

class YourApiView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSuperUser]
```

If this is not enough information for you, I would suggest that you follow **[Django REST Framework's tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/)**.

Comment: could u write an example ban logic please

Comment: @MahdiSorkhmiri - I cannot write the ban logic for you, no. You would have to design that for yourself. I have no idea what your requirements for your logic would be. This is something you would have to do for yourself, and if you have problems, come back to StackOverflow.